# How Solve 'RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory'?

Tags: python, pytorch

I import torch and run simple code using `cuda`, but `RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory` error occurred.

My code and error is:

```
>>> import torch
>>> print(torch.rand(1, device="cuda"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory
```

Comment: Make sure that no other processes are using your GPU and if they are, kill them or let them finish. Otherwise reboot. Otherwise your GPU doesn't have enough memory to support PyTorch

Comment: check your gpu memory by "watch  -n 0.5 nvidia-smi"

Comment: Is any other process using GPU memory?

Answer (score 0):

I worked with `torch` met with same issue, the problem solved by the following code:

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '2, 3'
```